# Sorted SQL groups

Tags: sql, sorting, group-by

I was trying to do something like:

```
SELECT
 a, b, c, MAX(d)
FROM
 table -- table with 4 columns a, b, c and d
GROUP BY
 a, b
```

I would like to have c as an additional value from the table that I do not want to group by, but that distinguish rows within groups. My problem is that GROUP BY makes c look like the first rows from groups and not the ones that really contain

```
d = MAX(d)
```

in the table.

ORDER BY is applied to the whole result, so it's not an option. Can I achieve that in any other way than sorting the table prematurely (as a subquery) and then applying the grouping? Would that work in every SQL engine? Do standards define such behaviors?

Edit1:

I tested something like:

```
SELECT
    t.*,
    MAX(d) AS v
FROM
    (SELECT
        a, b, c, d
    FROM
        table
    ORDER BY
        d DESC) AS t
GROUP BY
    a, b
```

and it works... but I do not think anybody can guarantee that the sort order will also be applied to the group rows... - maybe it works this way in MySQL, but how will it go with Oracle or PostgreSQL?

Comment: What database system do you use? This kind of expressions you are searching for are called analytic expressions. Using group by you are facing the issue/limit, that you cannot select columns that are not aggregated or not in the group by list. You could use something like max(d) over (partition by a,b) without a group by.

Comment: This should not matter. I want it to be as close to the standards as possible. Even SQL99 would do in this case.

Comment: Then use it. It is implemented in SQLServer, Oracle, PostreSQL, .. .

Comment: @wumpz: the SQL standard calls them "window functions". Analytical functions is what Oracle called them before this was part of the standard

Comment: Btw: there is no `SORT BY` in SQL

Comment: If you use `GROUP BY a,b` then {a,b} is unique for the result set (kind of a primary key). You can select the MAX(d) (or the min() or the sum() or the count(), etc) for the other columns , such as `d`, but if there are multiple values for `c` : which one do you want ?

Comment: I want the value that has MAX(d) = d. So let's put it this way, I want to do something like:
SELECT a, b, c, d FROM table ->
GROUP BY a, b ->
FILTER GROUPS SO THAT ROWS IN GROUPS <a, b, c, d> HAVE QUALITY OF d = MAX(d) (within the group) ->
LEAVE ONE REPRESENTATIVE PER GROUP.

Comment: If you want only one representative per group, and there happen to be more than one (with different values for c) : which one(s) do you want?

Comment: Any for which MAX(d) = d.

Answer (score 2):

This is ANSI SQL:

```
SELECT a, 
       b, 
       c, 
       MAX(d) over (partition by a,b) as max_d
FROM the_table
```

This will still return all rows from the table. The max value will repeated for every row that is returned. If you want to get *only* the rows with the max value you need to wrap this in a derived table:

```
select a,b,c,d
from (
  SELECT a, 
         b, 
         c,  
         d,
         MAX(d) over (partition by a,b) as max_d
  FROM the_table
) t 
where d = max_d;
```

That will return multiple rows if the same max value occurs more than once. If you only want a single row for each max value you need to use `row_number()`

Comment: That query could be fixed with a simple grouping. Which answer did you refer to as "jeroenh answer"?

Comment: @user767849: It seems that jeroenh has deleted his answer since I posted. And I don't understand what you mean with "could be fixed with simpl grouping". You can not get additional non-grouped columns from the table if you are using `group by`. Column `C` in your example query cannot be included in that query precisely for that reason. If this is not what you want then you need to add some sample data and the expected output.

Comment: Sadly, 'partition by' is not supported by all widely used database engines - for instance MySQL, so I cannot use it...

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
select x.*,y.c from 
(SELECT a, b, MAX(d) as d FROM table GROUP BY a, b) x,(select c,d from table) y
where x.d = y.d
```

Comment: It would produce additional rows that are not in the groups from the original query due to the fact a, b and c can be any any values that <a, b, _, d> exists in x and <_, _, c, d> exists in y - where no relation between a, b and c is stated. But I am aware of those workarounds. My question was about specific constructions or how to build query around those that let you "sort within groups before returning the actual result as group representatives".